# Kivy scrolling through thousands of lines of text

Tags: android, python, scrollview, kivy

So I am working on a kivy based app where I want to be able to scroll through thousands of lines of text. I started trying to use the basic scrollview, but that simply doesn't work (as far as I can tell) when you have massive amount of text. In fact, when I create a label that is significantly large it tends to just not render at all.

I then tried to just create my own widget to scroll the text by basically making a label that shows a subset of the entire text I want to show, and then iterates through the lines, so it would be like scrolling in a terminal. The problem I have now is that I cannot figure out how to get the label to stay the same size at the same place. I set the size and the size_hint and neither of them work. the text_size seems to kind of work, but I have a problem where the text jumps around horizontally depending on the line length, where sometimes it seems the label is centered on the x position I have it set to, rather than making that position the left edge. I have tried explicitly left aligning the text with no effect as well. I am trying to do this in a float layout.

If somebody would explain how I can scroll through a massive amount of text with kivy, I wouldbe very grateful. Thanks

edit: adding some code

```
Label:
    id: scroll_label_text
    font_size: 18
    text: "log here"
    x:800
```

this is in the kv file for the label I use to show the text I want to scroll through

```
log_text = ObjectProperty(Label)

scroll_down = ObjectProperty(Button)
scroll_up = ObjectProperty(Button)

scrollpos = 0

def __init__(self, log, **kwargs):
    super(Reader,self).__init__()
    self.scroll_down.bind(on_press=self.scroll)
    self.scroll_up.bind(on_press=self.scroll)
    self.log_text.y = self.scroll_down.height*2
    self.log_text.text_size = (None,300)

    self.log_text.shorten = True
```

so I have buttons for scrolling up and down by simply changing the slice of text that is displayed in the label.

the problem I have with this is that I can't the the label to remain at the left side of the screen. It seems to center around the 'x' setting(the numbers don't exactly indicate that though), so depending on the line length the texture size and thus position changes.

Comment: Can you provide some code to clarify this situation?

Comment: What about trying a TextInput with readonly set to True? I don't know if it would work... worth a try perhaps. Also, you probably shouldn't use size and size_hint at the same time, in case you were. If you are using size for instance, then set size_hint to (None, None) or it may interfere with sizing.

Comment: ok, I added some more info and code. Let me know if I can do anything else. I wasn't using size and size_hint at the same item, but I have tried both. If you think a textinput would be better I will try it (later), but im pretty sure im just having trouble grasping how the widget positioning works in kivy, which wouldn't be helped by a text input.

Comment: perhaps check out these: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.text.text_layout.html - never saw the textlayout before, doesn't sound too well maintained, but might be helpful. I assume you've scanned the label api, if not there are a couple of methods that look like they could come in handy, perhaps some usage of padding and split_str http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html

Comment: your code doesn't look like any implementation of kivy i've seen before, I have a feeling you haven't read the docs well. I recommend doing some tutorials. For instance, your label in the kv file doesn't have any sizing and very suspect looking positioning. Just setting x doesn't seem right here. Lack of positioning in particular may well be causing your problems. I will post here tomorrow if it's still an issue, as I don't have time now, but google it all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the suggestion of thopiekar on github: https://github.com/openBergisch/kivy-widget-playground/issues/1

Use the MultiLineLabel inside of an ScrollView and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackLayout>:
    id:rootpane
    textpane:textpane 
    scroll:scroll
    direction:'tb-lr'
    size_hint:(None, None)
    size:(480, 854)
    pos:self.parent.pos
    ScrollView:
        id:scroll
        size_hint:(None, None)
        size:rootpane.size
        #do_scroll_x:False
        #do_scroll_y:False
        bar_color:(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
        bar_inactiv_color:(0, 0, 0.7, 0.4)
        bar_margin:2
        bar_width:8
        #on_scroll_x:textpane.focus = True
        #on_scroll_y:textpane.focus = True
        TextInput:
            size_hint:(None, None)
            id:textpane
            text:''
            on_text:self.y = self.minimum_height
```

This works well except the resizing of `textinput` should be handled manually, if you set the text property to the content of a file. The last line show how, by the `on_text` property event.